# ReactJs : Nested routes inside component don't work properly after protecting the component in App.js with Private route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-router-component

Originally this is how the route looks like in **App.js**:

> App.js

```
<Route
  path="/home"
  name="Home"
  render={props => <DefaultLayout {...props} />
/>
```

> DefaultLayout.js

```
<Switch>
  {routes.map((route, idx) => {
    return route.component ? (
      <Route
        key={idx}
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        name={route.name}
        render={props => <route.component {...props} />}
      />
    ) : null;
  })}
  <Redirect from="/home" to="/home/dashboard" />
</Switch>
```

So basically, the **/home** route directs to **DefaultLayout** component which contains all the **nested routes** of the app. This works **perfectly**.
Since, only the authenticated user should have access to the home page, I have implemented a **PrivateRoute component** :

> PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

> App.js

```
<PrivateRoute
  exact
  name="Home"
  path="/home"
  component={DefaultLayout}
/>
```

Now, I get a **blank screen** after logging-in. (Although I do get redirected to **/home/dashboard**). So the internal routing of the **DefaultLayout** component, doesn't work like properly anymore.
**REMARK:** I've found-out that the nested-routes inside **DefaultLayout** component have to be defined inside **App.js** for them to work.   For example:

> DefaultLayout.js

```
 <Redirect from="/home" to="/home/dashboard" />
```

> App.js

```
<PrivateRoute
  exact
  name="Dashboard"
  path="/home/dashboard"
  component={Dashboard}
/>
```

But, I can't do this for all routes. The strange thing is that before using PrivateRoute, the **nested routes** worked **perfectly**. And I don't understand why the **PrivateRoute** component made the **nested-routing** inside **DashboardLayout** not function **properly**?

Comment: did you find the solution I am facing the same problem